# Composite or FilterPredicate query on Ref'd entity

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, objectify, datastore

Here's what I have:

```
class A{
  Ref<foo> b;
  Ref<foo> c;
  int      code;
  Date     timestamp
}
```

The pseudo "where" clause of the SQL statement would like like this:

where b = object or (c = object and code = 1) order by timestamp

In plain English, give me all the records of A if b equals the specific object or if c equals the specified object when code equals 1.  Order the result w/ timestamp.

Is the composite query part even possible w/ datastore (Objectify)?  I really don't want to do two queries and merge the results, because I have to sort by timestamp.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.  I already tried

```
new FilterPredicate(b, EQUAL, object)
```

This didn't work, because the entity type is not a support type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a native datastore `Key` object to the `FilterPredicate`. The Google SDK `Key`, not the generic Objectify `Key<?>`.

Normally when filtering on properties, Objectify translates `Ref<?>` and `Key<?>` objects to native datastore keys for you. With the google-supplied `FilterPredicate`, that isn't an option. So you have to do the translation manually.

Objectify stores all `Key<?>` and `Ref<?>` fields and native datastore `Key`s, so you can freely interchange them (or even change the type of fields if you want).